# GitHub doesn't show the correct dates of my commits as they are stored locally

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I have rebased my commits to change their dates, and right now it is showing the correct dates locally. Then, I decided to delete the remote repository and publish it again from the beginning with the correct dates. But, I was surprised to see that all dates of the commits, I have rebased, having the same date of the rebasing time!

Here is a screenshot of the commits locally:
[image]

And you can see the commits history on my public repo here:
https://github.com/Mohammed-Sharaf-Eddeen/epl-dashboard/commits/master

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Commits have *two* dates, and GitHub is showing you different ones than your GUI picked.

Ordinary `git commit` and `git merge` set both the author and committer dates to right now.

`git rebase` and kin set the committer date to right now (and you), leaving the author date (and the author name/email)  as they are in the original commits.

GitHub's showing you the committer date, your GUI is showing you the author date.

Comment: `git push` copies commits. It does not change them. I see the dates your UI shows and what seem to be the rebase dates you've mentioned in the commits I fetched from GitHub. I did `git log --pretty=%h\ %cI\ %aI\ %s` to check.

Comment: Is it possible you're seeing dates on GitHub in local time from some other time zone? Are you using a VPN?

Comment: Following up on your answer, I had already tried the change the GIT_COMMITTER_DATE and the GIT_AUTHOR_DATE in my rebase, and I thought I already did. But after your clarification, it turned out that I only changed the the GIT_AUTHOR_DATE. I am not quite sure what I have done wrong during my rebase, but I rebased again and used this flag --committer-date-is-author-date and right now all is good! Thanks!